# Python string formatting - old `%` vs new `str.format`

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, string-formatting

New formatting lets us do this: `'{:.<12}'.format('##')` - optional fill character.
Can we do that using old formatting?
(I know we can fill with spaces `'%-12s' % '##'` )

Also, old formatting lets us do this: `'%-*s' % (12, '##')` - variable length.
Can we do that using new formatting?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For doing variable length using new-format , you can use nesting of replacements -

```
>>> '{:{}<{}}'.format('##','.',12)
'##..........'
>>> '{:{}<{}}'.format('##','-',12)
'##----------'
>>> '{:{}<{}}'.format('##','-',20)
'##------------------'
```

Even spaces as fill character -

```
>>> '{:{}<{}}'.format('##',' ',20)
'##                  '
```

Please note you do not always need to use nesting of replacements, you can directly specify them in the format as well -

```
>>> '{: <12}'.format('##')
'##          '
```

You can also specify the position of each argument to decide which argument goes where. Example -

```
>>> '{2:{0}<{1}}'.format('.',12,'##')
'##..........'
>>> '{0:{1}<{2}}'.format('##','-',20)
'##------------------'
```

Comment: Hmm , Would like to hear what is wrong in my answer.

Answer (score 3):

With `format` you can nest the replacements:

```
'{:.<{}}'.format('##',12)
```

So `format` is more powerful. Optional fill characters are not possible with `%`.

Answer (score 1):

For your first part of the question, you can left align and use a space as the fill char using a width of 12:

`'%-*s' % (12, '##')` can be replaced with  `'{: <12}'.format('##')`.

For the second part no you cannot specify the fill character with old style formatting.

There is a nice site [here](https://pyformat.info/)  that shows most of what you can and cannot do with old vs new, a snippet that covers Padding and aligning strings:

**Padding and aligning strings**

> By default values are formatted to take up only as many characters as needed to represent the content. It is however also possible to define that a value should be padded to a specific length.
>
> Unfortunately the default alignment differs between old and new style formatting. The old style defaults to right aligned while for new style it's left.

```
Align right:

Old '%10s' % ('test',) 
New '{:>10}'.format('test')

Align left:

Old

'%-10s' % ('test',)
New

'{:10}'.format('test')
```

**By argument:**

> In the previous example, the value '10' is encoded as part of the format string. However, it is possible to also supply such values as an argument.

```
Old

'%*s' % ((- 8), 'test')
New

'{:<{}s}'.format('test', 8)
```

> Again, new style formatting surpasses the old variant by providing more control over how values are padded and aligned.
>   You are able to choose the padding character:

**This operation is not available with old-style formatting.**

```
New

'{:_<10}'.format('test')
Output
```

> And also center align values:

**This operation is not available with old-style formatting.**

```
New

'{:^10}'.format('test')
```

Comment: For the first part, idea was to have variable length. Nested formating solved that. Thanks for the [pyformat](https://pyformat.info/) link!

Comment: no prob, then nesting the `{}` will do the job `'{: <{}}'.format('##',var)` or  `'{: <{var}}'.format('##,var=var')`